# Xcode not reflecting changes in the code to the simulator and device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode4.3

This never happened to me before. I have my code which was working fine and yesterday morning after updating my code from GitHub, the Xcode did not accept changes and installed the previous build. I removed my project, deleted Git client and cloned a new project, which didn't work while running on simulator. I tried installing app on device and it was running fine!

Later in the evening I created an AdHoc and I had the same issue (AdHoc was same as simulator build!).

Today morning I removed the Xcode and installed the new Xcode Version 4.3. However the problem still exists. I can not see my new changes on Simulator and on device. The same code is working fine for my friend. (I have cleaned the project many times, removed the project from Organizer-? project). Nothing seems to work.

EDIT:

I formatted my computer.

Now there should be no reason for it to show me old code. I even got the fresh copy from Repo... The worst thing is, it's still showing me something different!

Why is it like this?

Answer (score 2):

Did you clean the build folder by pressing command while the cursor is on the clean option? Are you sure you don't have two instances of the app installed? Try turning your iPhone off and on.. Sounds dumb but has worked for me in the past

Answer (score 2):

The most practical way is not losing time and closing and opening XCode, it commonly solves it. Sometimes even you have to reboot...for example in this error case:

```
Couldn't register com.XXXXX.deviceapp with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error    code. This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

1.First of all change assistant editor to standard editor.
2.open viewContraller.swift file for initial view and `print("something")` in `viewDidLoad()` 
3.if it works you have no any problem.

But you have to do the following things when working with the assistant editor,

now open the main.storyboard and select initial view.
Now open the assistant editor and make sure you have selected viewController correctly.

you can set it as follow,

Click on -> Automatic -> related viewController.swift (you can find it on top of the assistant editor)

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning and building your friends project.

Answer (score 0):

Still happening in 11/2017

xCode (that day, never seen it before) is not saving changes in code in Assistant editor mode. Even linking IBOutlet doesn't work.

If you go back to Standard Editor you loose all your new code, nice...

Better stay in Standard Editor

Answer (score 0):

Delete the installed app on device / simulator and try to run.